# Does anyone know why the div element created in jQuery is not being displayed?

Tags: jquery

The jQuery file is already downloaded

```
<script>    
    $("<div/>")
        .css({width:100, height:100, border:"2px solid black"})
        .appendTo("body");
</script>
```

Comment: show some html...to what element div refers to?

Comment: Do you have any errors in the console?

Comment: Did you do any debugging yourself? Please read the documentation about what a good SO question needs: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

This is merely a demo to show that
your script works as it is:

```js
$("<div/>")
 .css({width:100,height:100,border:"2px solid black"})
 .appendTo("body");
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
```

It creates a `<div>` element and appends it to the body. What else did you expect it to so?